# Using Javascript to load .tpl displays it wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

I am trying to load some code with Javascript on a button click. The problem is that some of the code is just displayed instead of executed.

This is the file reload.tpl I am trying to load:

```
<div class="online-players">
  {% for player in players_online %}
  <div class="online-player-heads">
    <a href="?page=player&name={{ player.getName }}">
        {{ player.getPlayerHead(64, 'img-polaroid', true)|raw }}
    </a>
  </div>
{% else %}
  <div class='force-center'><em>{{ 'no_players_online'|trans }}</em></div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I use this to load the code:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button2').click(function() {
            $('.online-players').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $(this).load('templates/default/views/reload.tpl', function() {
                    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Expected:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRMGn.png

What actually is happening:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UvG7.png

Anyone knows why it's doing this? When I am not trying to load through a script it's working just fine. but as soon as I try the .load, it just doesnt display right..
Help? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load smarty tpl with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096651/load-smarty-tpl-with-jquery)

Comment: Pretty sure it's not. This has something to do with Smarty I believe..

Comment: You can't expect to get generated template file if you just load it like that, the template needs to be processed by template engine first.

Comment: Mind helping me? I have no idea how to do that :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you did not discover by yourself, this is what you need to do:

Change target page on jquery load to a php file (in order to proper server-side handle):

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button2').click(function() {
        $('.online-players').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).load('reload.php', function() {
                $(this).fadeIn("slow");
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Inside reload.php file:

```
require_once("./libs/Smarty.class.php");
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->display("templates/default/views/reload.tpl");
```

I hope this will help you.
Regards,

Comment: Thank you for replying, and I am sorry for being so late.
I can't find any Smarty.class.php, or anything alike. There is however Vendor / Composer which I have no idea how to use. Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

smarty is a server-side templating engine for PHP. You can either use AJAX to call the file and let php/smarty handle the conversion to html or make a copy of the file and convert it to javascript so it works withing the browser.